# Removing duplicates in Dictionary Key

Tags: c#

I have the below dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
test.Add("1|1", "blue");
test.Add("1|2", "Nice");
test.Add("1|3", "Jaish");
test.Add("2|2", "Muna");
test.Add("3|1", "haha");
test.Add("3|2", "green");
test.Add("4|1", "red");
Dictionary<string, string> test2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in test)
{
    if (!test2.ContainsValue(entry.Key))
        test2.Add(entry.Key, entry.Key);
}
```

I want to remove the below duplicate values:

```
test.Add("1|2", "Nice");
test.Add("1|3", "Jaish");
test.Add("3|2", "green")
```

So after removing the duplicates the `Dictionary`'s key count should be 4.

Comment: They are not duplicates. You can't have duplicate key in the Dictionary

Comment: I know that dictionary key  does not contain the duplicates.But i want the unique dictionary key count.

Comment: What is your definition of *duplicate*? `1|2`, `1|3` and `3|2` are three different values, hence they are not duplicates.

Comment: Among your entries, there are neither duplicate keys nor duplicate values. Please specify what a *duplicate* is from *your* problem's point of view.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that duplicates are defined through the first part of the pipe-splitted string:

```
var uniques = test.GroupBy(kv => kv.Key.Split('|')[0])
                  .Select(g => g.First())
                  .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

This selects always the first key-value pair of each group.

Comment: +1 for clarifying the question, But Tim, can you be sure that it will always select `1|1` against the `First()`, I think the order can't be guaranteed.

Comment: @Habib: The order doesn't matter for OP, at least he hasn't mentioned it. So understand `First` as _whatever_. If there's something to order by, he needs `OrderBy` before `First` or use the [overload with the predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes for the above code, but if you just change the order of adding in the dictionary for example add `"1|2"` before `"1|1"`, then you will get the wrong result. But in the end it doesn't matter if the OP is happy with it

Answer (score 1):

Implement `IEqualityComparer<string>` which will not allow you insert duplicate items

```
var test = new Dictionary<string, string>(new MyStringEqualityComparer());
```

...

```
public class MyStringEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Split('|')[0] == y.Split('|')[0];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.Split('|')[0].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sharing your thoughts,But i need this type of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your example is contrived and you don't want to use those pipe-delimited keys...

The simplest way to do this is not to use Dictionary.Add(..), but instead just set the value

```
test["1"] = "blue";
test["1"] = "NICE";
test["1"] = "Jaish";

Debug.Assert(test.Count == 1);
```

However, you have to decide if this is the logic that you want, that it just overwrites every time

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `|` symbols in your input's keys should be interpreted to mean "or". If that's the case, you can first split out the keys to produce new key-value pairs for each key part:

```
var test2 = test.SelectMany(kvp =>
    kvp.Key.Split('|').Select(k =>
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, kvp.Value)));
```

...then take just the first value for each new key:

```
var test3 = test2.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                 .Select(g => g.First())
                 .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the | means OR then you can produce a new *unique* dictionary like this.

```
var oredDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var kv in test.ToArray())
{
    var keys = kv.Key.Split('|').Select(int.Parse);
    oredDict[keys.First() | keys.Last()] = kv.Value;
}
```